# Extracting information from HTML with XSLT 3.0 when data is grouped visually as siblings in a td separated by blank lines

Tags: html, web-scraping, xpath, xslt

I have a work-in-progress where I'm using XSLT 3 to extract information from some preprocessed archaic HTML. I'd like to produce JSON showing the relationships between the various entities for further loading, replacing part of our existing pipeline which uses some frankly nightmarish Python.

We've used this approach to good effect elsewhere, but I'm encountering some unique challenges with this input.

One of the challenges here is that the attorneys for one party are all in one `td` consisting of `b`, `text()` and `i` elements, with the individual attorneys grouped by blank lines. I've used `xsl:for-each-group` to handle this, which seems to be the standard approach, but is interfering with other of my challenges. Specifically, there's some attorneys whose address is listed as "(See above for address)", which needs to be resolved correctly before loading.

My first thought was to use `xsl:key` or `xsl:accumulator` to create a map of valid addresses with the name as the key, but I couldn't figure out how to express "the address" coherently in Xpath when starting from the `b` tag that contains the attorney name, nor how to effectively use `xsl:accumulator` in conjunction with `xsl:for-each-group`. My eventual solution was to simply create a map in a variable, but this feels messy and redundant. Is there a better way?

The other style question I'd like to ask is about the use of `mode`. Using an unbounded `xsl:apply-templates` introduced a significant peformance hit, but I wanted to keep the approach of "This kind of table represents all the parties and should produce a map-entry with an array, these kinds of rows represent a party and should produce a map-entry in that array," etc. I settled on using a `apply-templates` elements with a `select` to specify which parts of the document to process while using `mode` with more generic template matches to let me group chains of templates to fire off for contained elements. This arrangement was more performant, but I'm wondering if there's a more accepted approach for this situation where a large input needs only specific pieces processed.

The transformation is being run in saxon-js with the `'-ns:##html5'` option enabled to avoid constantly restating the `html` namespace in Xpaths.

Input (lightly edited to remove a tremendous number of case history table rows):

```
<html:html xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><html:head><html:title>CM/ECF LIVE - U.S. District Court:txed - Docket Report</html:title></html:head><html:body bgcolor="66FFFF" text="000000">

                <html:table align="right" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="5">
                    <html:tbody><html:tr><html:td align="right">CLOSED, FRC, JURY, MEDIATION</html:td></html:tr>
                </html:tbody></html:table><html:br/>
            <html:h3 align="center">&#160;
U.S. District Court [LIVE]<html:br/>
Eastern District of TEXAS LIVE (Texarkana)<html:br/>
CIVIL DOCKET FOR CASE #: 5:01-cv-00302-DF</html:h3>
<html:table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="5"><html:tbody><html:tr>
<html:td valign="top" width="60%"><html:br/>Broadcom Corporation v. Intel Corporation<html:br/>
Assigned to: Judge David Folsom<html:br/>
Demand: $0<html:br/>
Cause: 35:145 Patent Infringement</html:td>
<html:td valign="top" width="40%"><html:br/>Date Filed: 11/19/2001<html:br/>
Nature of Suit: 830 Patent<html:br/>
Jurisdiction: Federal Question</html:td>
</html:tr></html:tbody></html:table>
<html:table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="5">
            <html:tbody><html:tr>
                <html:td><html:b><html:u>Mediator</html:u></html:b></html:td>
            </html:tr>
        
            <html:tr>
                <html:td valign="top" width="40%">
                    <html:b>Robert M Parker</html:b>
        </html:td>
<html:td valign="top" width="20%" align="right">represented&#160;by</html:td><html:td valign="top" width="40%"><html:b>Robert M Parker</html:b>
<html:br/>Parker Clayton
<html:br/>100 E Ferguson
<html:br/>Suite 1114
<html:br/>Tyler, TX 75702
<html:br/>903-533-9288
<html:br/>Email: rmparker@pbatyler.com
<html:br/>PRO SE</html:td></html:tr><html:tr><html:td/></html:tr>

            <html:tr>
                <html:td><html:b><html:u>Plaintiff</html:u></html:b></html:td>
            </html:tr>
        
            <html:tr>
                <html:td valign="top" width="40%">
                    <html:b>Broadcom Corporation</html:b>
        </html:td>
<html:td valign="top" width="20%" align="right">represented&#160;by</html:td><html:td valign="top" width="40%"><html:b>Nicholas H Patton</html:b>
<html:br/>Patton &amp; Tidwell
<html:br/>4605 Texas Blvd
<html:br/>PO Box 5398
<html:br/>Texarkana, TX 75505-5398
<html:br/>903/792-7080
<html:br/>Fax: 19037928233
<html:br/>Email: nickpatton@texarkanalaw.com
<html:br/><html:i>LEAD ATTORNEY</html:i>
<html:br/><html:i>ATTORNEY TO BE NOTICED</html:i><html:br/><html:br/>
<html:b>Alda C Leu</html:b>
<html:br/>Wilson Sonsini Goodrich &amp; Rosati
<html:br/>650 Page Mill Road
<html:br/>Palo Alto, CA 94304-1050
<html:br/>650-493-9300
<html:br/>Fax: 16505655100<html:br/><html:br/>
<html:b>Alice Catherine Garber</html:b>
<html:br/>Kirkland &amp; Ellis LLP - California
<html:br/>555 California St
<html:br/>Floor 24
<html:br/>San Francisco, CA 94104
<html:br/>415/439-1452
<html:br/>Fax: 415/439-1352
<html:br/>Email: agarber@kirkland.com<html:br/><html:br/>
<html:b>Andrew S Dallmann</html:b>
<html:br/>McDermott Will &amp; Emery
<html:br/>3150 Porter Drive
<html:br/>Palo Alto, Ca 94304
<html:br/>650/813-500
<html:br/>Fax: 16508135100
<html:br/><html:i>ATTORNEY TO BE NOTICED</html:i><html:br/><html:br/>
<html:b>Behrooz Shariati</html:b>
<html:br/>McDermott Will Emery
<html:br/>3150 Porter Drive
<html:br/>Palo Alto, CA 94304-1212
<html:br/>650/813-5000
<html:br/>Fax: 16508135100
<html:br/>Email: bshariati@mwe.com<html:br/><html:br/>
<html:b>Bradford J Goodson</html:b>
<html:br/>Wilson Sonsini Goodrich &amp; Rosati
<html:br/>650 Page Mill Road
<html:br/>Palo Alto, CA 94304-1050
<html:br/>650-493-9300
<html:br/>Fax: 16505655100<html:br/><html:br/>
<html:b>Christopher D Bright</html:b>
<html:br/>McDermott Will &amp; Emergy
<html:br/>18191 Von Karman Ave
<html:br/>Suite 500
<html:br/>Irvine, Ca 92612
<html:br/>949-851-0633
<html:br/>Fax: 19498519348
<html:br/>Email: cbright@mwe.com<html:br/><html:br/>
<html:b>David A Caine</html:b>
<html:br/>Wilson Sonsini Goodrich &amp; Rosati
<html:br/>650 Page Mill Road
<html:br/>Palo Alto, CA 94304-1050
<html:br/>650-493-9300
<html:br/>Fax: 16505655100
<html:br/>Email: dcaine@wsgr.com<html:br/><html:br/>
<html:b>David L Fligor</html:b>
<html:br/>Wilson Sonsini Goodrich &amp; Rosati
<html:br/>650 Page Mill Road
<html:br/>Palo Alto, CA 94304-1050
<html:br/>650-493-9300
<html:br/>Fax: 650-493-9300<html:br/><html:br/>
<html:b>David C Wang</html:b>
<html:br/>Wilson Sonsini Goodrich &amp; Rosati
<html:br/>650 Page Mill Road
<html:br/>Palo Alto, CA 94304-1050
<html:br/>650-493-9300
<html:br/>Fax: 650-493-9300<html:br/><html:br/>
<html:b>Irwin R Gross</html:b>
<html:br/>Wilson Sonsini Goodrich &amp; Rosati
<html:br/>650 Page Mill Road
<html:br/>Palo Alto, CA 94304-1050
<html:br/>650-493-9300
<html:br/>Fax: 650-493-9300<html:br/><html:br/>
<html:b>J Thad Heartfield</html:b>
<html:br/>Law Offices of J. Thad Heartfield
<html:br/>2195 Dowlen Rd
<html:br/>Beaumont, TX 77706
<html:br/>409/866-3318
<html:br/>Fax: 14098665789
<html:br/>Email: thad@jth-law.com
<html:br/><html:i>ATTORNEY TO BE NOTICED</html:i><html:br/><html:br/>
<html:b>James C Yoon</html:b>
<html:br/>Wilson Sonsini Goodrich &amp; Rosati
<html:br/>650 Page Mill Road
<html:br/>Palo Alto, CA 94304-1050
<html:br/>650-493-9300
<html:br/>Fax: 16504936811
<html:br/>Email: jyoon@wsgr.com<html:br/><html:br/>
<html:b>Jennifer L Yokoyama</html:b>
<html:br/>McDermott Will &amp; Emergy
<html:br/>18191 Von Karman Ave
<html:br/>Suite 500
<html:br/>Irvine, Ca 92612
<html:br/>949/851-0633
<html:br/>Fax: 949/851-9348
<html:br/>Email: jyokoyama@mwe.com<html:br/><html:br/>
<html:b>Julie M Holloway</html:b>
<html:br/>Wilson Sonsini Goodrich &amp; Rosati
<html:br/>650 Page Mill Road
<html:br/>Palo Alto, CA 94304-1050
<html:br/>650-493-9300
<html:br/>Fax: 16504936811
<html:br/>Email: jholloway@wsgr.com<html:br/><html:br/>
<html:b>Keaton S Parekh</html:b>
<html:br/>Wilson Sonsini Goodrich &amp; Rosati
<html:br/>650 Page Mill Rd
<html:br/>Palo Alto, CA 94304-1050
<html:br/>650/493-9300
<html:br/>Fax: 650/493-9300<html:br/><html:br/>
<html:b>Matthew R Reed</html:b>
<html:br/>Wilson Sonsini Goodrich &amp; Rosati
<html:br/>650 Page Mill Road
<html:br/>Palo Alto, CA 94304-1050
<html:br/>650/565-3990
<html:br/>Fax: 650/493-6811
<html:br/>Email: mreed@wsgr.com<html:br/><html:br/>
<html:b>Matthew F Weil</html:b>
<html:br/>McDermott Will &amp; Emergy
<html:br/>18191 Von Karman Ave
<html:br/>Suite 500
<html:br/>Irvine, Ca 92612
<html:br/>949-851-0633
<html:br/>Fax: 19498519348<html:br/><html:br/>
<html:b>Michael A Ladra</html:b>
<html:br/>Wilson Sonsini Goodrich &amp; Rosati
<html:br/>650 Page Mill Road
<html:br/>Palo Alto, CA 94304-1050
<html:br/>650-320-4869
<html:br/>Fax: 16504936811
<html:br/>Email: mladra@wsgr.com<html:br/><html:br/>
<html:b>Michael R O'Neill</html:b>
<html:br/>McDermott Will &amp; Emery - Irvine
<html:br/>18191 Von Karman Avenue
<html:br/>Suite 400
<html:br/>Irvine, CA 92612-7108
<html:br/>949/851-0633
<html:br/>Fax: 949/851-9348
<html:br/>Email: moneill@mwe.com<html:br/><html:br/>
<html:b>Robert J Blanch</html:b>
<html:br/>McDermott Will &amp; Emery
<html:br/>3150 Porter Drive
<html:br/>Palo Alto, Ca 94304
<html:br/>650/813-500
<html:br/>Fax: 16508135100
<html:br/><html:i>ATTORNEY TO BE NOTICED</html:i><html:br/><html:br/>
<html:b>Ron E Shulman</html:b>
<html:br/>Wilson Sonsini Goodrich &amp; Rosati
<html:br/>650 Page Mill Road
<html:br/>Palo Alto, CA 94304-1050
<html:br/>650-496-4083
<html:br/>Email: rshulman@wsgr.com<html:br/><html:br/>
<html:b>Stephen J Ferenchick</html:b>
<html:br/>Wilson Sonsini Goodrich &amp; Rosati
<html:br/>650 Page Mill Road
<html:br/>Palo Alto, CA 94304-1050
<html:br/>650-493-9300
<html:br/>Fax: 16505655100<html:br/><html:br/>
<html:b>Theresa E Norton</html:b>
<html:br/>Wilson Sonsini Goodrich &amp; Rosati
<html:br/>650 Page Mill Road
<html:br/>Palo Alto, CA 94304-1050
<html:br/>650-493-9300
<html:br/>Fax: 16505655100<html:br/><html:br/>
<html:b>Tung-On Kong</html:b>
<html:br/>Wilson Sonsini Goodrich &amp; Rosati
<html:br/>650 Page Mill Road
<html:br/>Palo Alto, CA 94304-1050
<html:br/>650-493-9300
<html:br/>Fax: 650-493-9300<html:br/><html:br/>
<html:b>Vera M Elson</html:b>
<html:br/>McDermott Will Emery
<html:br/>3150 Porter Drive
<html:br/>Palo Alto, CA 94304-1212
<html:br/>650/813-5000
<html:br/>Fax: 650/813-5000</html:td></html:tr><html:tr><html:td/></html:tr>
<html:tr><html:td valign="top"><html:br/>V.<html:br/></html:td></html:tr>

            <html:tr>
                <html:td><html:b><html:u>Defendant</html:u></html:b></html:td>
            </html:tr>
        
            <html:tr>
                <html:td valign="top" width="40%">
                    <html:b>Intel Corporation</html:b> <html:br/><html:i>a Delaware Corporation</html:i>
        </html:td>
<html:td valign="top" width="20%" align="right">represented&#160;by</html:td><html:td valign="top" width="40%"><html:b>Damon Michael Young</html:b>
<html:br/>Young Pickett &amp; Lee
<html:br/>4122 Texas Blvd
<html:br/>PO Box 1897
<html:br/>Texarkana, TX 75504-1897
<html:br/>903/794-1303
<html:br/>Fax: 19037925098
<html:br/>Email: dyoung@youngpickettlaw.com
<html:br/><html:i>TERMINATED: 01/28/2002</html:i>
<html:br/><html:i>LEAD ATTORNEY</html:i>
<html:br/><html:i>ATTORNEY TO BE NOTICED</html:i><html:br/><html:br/>
<html:b>Andrew D Skale</html:b>
<html:br/>Fish &amp; Richardson - San Diego
<html:br/>12390 El Camino Real
<html:br/>San Diego, CA 92130
<html:br/>858/678-5070
<html:br/>Fax: 858/678-5099
<html:br/>Email: skale@fr.com<html:br/><html:br/>
<html:b>Daniel T Pascucci</html:b>
<html:br/>Fish &amp; Richardson
<html:br/>4350 La Jolla Village Drive
<html:br/>Suite 500
<html:br/>San Diego, Ca 92122
<html:br/>858-678-5070
<html:br/>Fax: 18586785099<html:br/><html:br/>
<html:b>David S Shuman</html:b>
<html:br/>Fish &amp; Richardson
<html:br/>12390 El Camino Real
<html:br/>San Diego, CA 92130
<html:br/>858-678-5070
<html:br/>Fax: 18586785099
<html:br/>Email: shuman@fr.com<html:br/><html:br/>
<html:b>Elton Joe Kendall</html:b>
<html:br/>Provost Umphrey - Dallas
<html:br/>3232 McKinney Ave
<html:br/>Suite 700
<html:br/>Dallas, TX 75204
<html:br/>214/744-3000
<html:br/>Fax: 12147443015
<html:br/>Email: jkendall@provostumphrey.com<html:br/><html:br/>
<html:b>Garret Wesley Chambers</html:b>
<html:br/>McKool Smith - Dallas
<html:br/>300 Crescent Court
<html:br/>Suite 1500
<html:br/>Dallas, TX 75201
<html:br/>214/978-4000
<html:br/>Fax: 12149784044
<html:br/>Email: gchambers@mckoolsmith.com<html:br/><html:br/>
<html:b>Janet Craycroft</html:b>
<html:br/>Intel Corporation
<html:br/>2200 Mission College Blvd SC4-202
<html:br/>Santa Clara, Ca 95052
<html:br/>408/765-4493
<html:br/>Fax: 14087655175<html:br/><html:br/>
<html:b>John A Dragseth</html:b>
<html:br/>Fish &amp; Richardson
<html:br/>3300 Dain Rauscher Plaza
<html:br/>60 South Sixth Street
<html:br/>Minneapolis, Mn 55402
<html:br/>612/335-5070
<html:br/>Fax: 16122889696
<html:br/>Email: dragseth@fr.com<html:br/><html:br/>
<html:b>John E Gartman</html:b>
<html:br/>Fish &amp; Richardson - San Diego
<html:br/>12390 El Camino Real
<html:br/>San Diego, CA 92130
<html:br/>858-678-5070
<html:br/>Fax: 18586785099
<html:br/>Email: gartman@fr.com<html:br/><html:br/>
<html:b>John W Thornburgh</html:b>
<html:br/>Fish &amp; Richardson - San Diego
<html:br/>12390 El Camino Real
<html:br/>San Diego, CA 92130
<html:br/>858/678-5070
<html:br/>Fax: 858/678-5099
<html:br/>Email: thornburgh@fr.com<html:br/><html:br/>
<html:b>Justin M Barnes</html:b>
<html:br/>Fish &amp; Richardson
<html:br/>4350 La Jolla Village Drive
<html:br/>Suite 500
<html:br/>San Diego, Ca 92122
<html:br/>858-678-5070
<html:br/>Fax: 18586785099<html:br/><html:br/>
<html:b>Lance Lee</html:b>
<html:br/>Young Pickett &amp; Lee
<html:br/>4122 Texas Blvd
<html:br/>PO Box 1897
<html:br/>Texarkana, TX 75504-1897
<html:br/>903/794-1303
<html:br/>Fax: 19037945098
<html:br/>Email: wlancelee@aol.com
<html:br/><html:i>TERMINATED: 01/28/2002</html:i><html:br/><html:br/>
<html:b>Lloyd A Farnham</html:b>
<html:br/>Keker &amp; Van Nest
<html:br/>710 Sansome St
<html:br/>San Francisco, CA 94111
<html:br/>415/391-5400
<html:br/>Fax: 14153977188<html:br/><html:br/>
<html:b>Michael Brett Johnson</html:b>
<html:br/>Fish &amp; Richardson - Dallas
<html:br/>1717 Main St.
<html:br/>Suite 5000
<html:br/>Dallas, TX 75201
<html:br/>(214)747-5070
<html:br/>Fax: 12147472091
<html:br/>Email: mbjohnson@fr.com<html:br/><html:br/>
<html:b>Robert A Van Nest</html:b>
<html:br/>Keker &amp; Van Nest
<html:br/>710 Sansome St
<html:br/>San Francisco, CA 94111
<html:br/>415/391-5400
<html:br/>Fax: 14153977188
<html:br/>Email: rvn@kvn.com<html:br/><html:br/>
<html:b>Samuel Franklin Baxter</html:b>
<html:br/>Attorney at Law
<html:br/>P O Box O
<html:br/>Marshall, TX 75671
<html:br/>903/927-2111
<html:br/>Fax: 19039272622
<html:br/>Email: sbaxter@mckoolsmith.com
<html:br/><html:i>ATTORNEY TO BE NOTICED</html:i><html:br/><html:br/>
<html:b>Seth M Sproul</html:b>
<html:br/>Fish &amp; Richardson - San Diego
<html:br/>12390 El Camino Real
<html:br/>San Diego, CA 92130
<html:br/>858-678-4343
<html:br/>Email: sproul@fr.com<html:br/><html:br/>
<html:b>Stuart L Gasner</html:b>
<html:br/>Keker &amp; Van Nest
<html:br/>710 Sansome St
<html:br/>San Francisco, CA 94111
<html:br/>415/391-5400
<html:br/>Fax: 14153977188<html:br/><html:br/>
<html:b>Thomas M Melsheimer</html:b>
<html:br/>Fish &amp; Richardson - Dallas
<html:br/>1717 Main St
<html:br/>5000 Bank One Center
<html:br/>Dallas, TX 75201
<html:br/>214/747-5070
<html:br/>Fax: 12147472091
<html:br/>Email: melsheimer@fr.com
<html:br/><html:i>ATTORNEY TO BE NOTICED</html:i></html:td></html:tr><html:tr><html:td/></html:tr>

            <html:tr>
                <html:td><html:b><html:u>Amicus</html:u></html:b></html:td>
            </html:tr>
        
            <html:tr>
                <html:td valign="top" width="40%">
                    <html:b>Gail Peterson</html:b> <html:br/><html:i>Technical Advisor on case</html:i>
        </html:td>
<html:td valign="top" width="20%" align="right">represented&#160;by</html:td><html:td valign="top" width="40%"><html:b>Gail Peterson</html:b>
<html:br/>Cox and Smith
<html:br/>112 E. Pecan Street
<html:br/>Suite 1800
<html:br/>San Antonio, TX 78205-1521
<html:br/>PRO SE</html:td></html:tr><html:tr><html:td/></html:tr>

            <html:tr>
                <html:td><html:b><html:u>Counter Claimant</html:u></html:b></html:td>
            </html:tr>
        
            <html:tr>
                <html:td valign="top" width="40%">
                    <html:b>Intel Corporation</html:b>
        </html:td>
<html:td valign="top" width="20%" align="right">represented&#160;by</html:td><html:td valign="top" width="40%"><html:b>Damon Michael Young</html:b>
<html:br/>(See above for address)
<html:br/><html:i>TERMINATED: 01/28/2002</html:i>
<html:br/><html:i>LEAD ATTORNEY</html:i>
<html:br/><html:i>ATTORNEY TO BE NOTICED</html:i><html:br/><html:br/>
<html:b>John W Thornburgh</html:b>
<html:br/>(See above for address)<html:br/><html:br/>
<html:b>Lance Lee</html:b>
<html:br/>(See above for address)
<html:br/><html:i>TERMINATED: 01/28/2002</html:i><html:br/><html:br/>
<html:b>Michael Brett Johnson</html:b>
<html:br/>(See above for address)<html:br/><html:br/>
<html:b>Thomas M Melsheimer</html:b>
<html:br/>(See above for address)
<html:br/><html:i>ATTORNEY TO BE NOTICED</html:i></html:td></html:tr><html:tr><html:td/></html:tr>
<html:tr><html:td valign="top"><html:br/>V.<html:br/></html:td></html:tr>

            <html:tr>
                <html:td><html:b><html:u>Counter Defendant</html:u></html:b></html:td>
            </html:tr>
        
            <html:tr>
                <html:td valign="top" width="40%">
                    <html:b>Broadcom Corporation</html:b>
        </html:td>
<html:td valign="top" width="20%" align="right">represented&#160;by</html:td><html:td valign="top" width="40%"><html:b>Nicholas H Patton</html:b>
<html:br/>(See above for address)
<html:br/><html:i>LEAD ATTORNEY</html:i>
<html:br/><html:i>ATTORNEY TO BE NOTICED</html:i><html:br/><html:br/>
<html:b>J Thad Heartfield</html:b>
<html:br/>(See above for address)
<html:br/><html:i>ATTORNEY TO BE NOTICED</html:i><html:br/><html:br/>
<html:b>Andrew S Dallmann</html:b>
<html:br/>(See above for address)
<html:br/><html:i>ATTORNEY TO BE NOTICED</html:i><html:br/><html:br/>
<html:b>Robert J Blanch</html:b>
<html:br/>(See above for address)
<html:br/><html:i>ATTORNEY TO BE NOTICED</html:i></html:td></html:tr><html:tr><html:td/></html:tr>
</html:tbody></html:table>
<html:br/><html:table align="center" width="99%" border="1" rules="all" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0"><html:tbody><html:tr><html:td width="94" nowrap=""><html:h4>Date Filed</html:h4></html:td>
<html:td align="center" width="60"><html:h4>#</html:h4></html:td><html:td align="center"><html:h4>Docket Text</html:h4></html:td></html:tr>
<html:tr><html:td width="94" nowrap="" valign="top">11/19/2001</html:td><html:td width="60" valign="top" align="right"><html:a href="/cgi-bin/show_case_doc?1,52660,,,,,2">1</html:a></html:td><html:td valign="top">Original Complaint with Jury Demand filed. Cause: 35:145 Patent Infringement (92 pages with exhibits) (sm) Modified on 11/20/2001 (Entered: 11/20/2001)</html:td></html:tr>
<html:tr><html:td width="94" nowrap="" valign="top">11/19/2001</html:td><html:td width="60" valign="top" align="right">&#160;</html:td><html:td valign="top"> Filing Fee Paid; FILING FEE $ 150 RECEIPT # 96539 (sm) (Entered: 11/20/2001)</html:td></html:tr>
<html:tr><html:td width="94" nowrap="" valign="top">11/19/2001</html:td><html:td width="60" valign="top" align="right">&#160;</html:td><html:td valign="top">Summons(es) issued for Intel Corporation (sm) (Entered: 11/20/2001)</html:td></html:tr>
<html:tr><html:td width="94" nowrap="" valign="top">11/20/2001</html:td><html:td width="60" valign="top" align="right">2</html:td><html:td valign="top">Form mailed to Commissioner of Patents and Trademarks. (sm) (Entered: 11/20/2001)</html:td></html:tr>
<html:tr><html:td width="94" nowrap="" valign="top">11/20/2001</html:td><html:td width="60" valign="top" align="right">&#160;</html:td><html:td valign="top">Magistrate consent forms mailed to Broadcom Corporation . (sm) (Entered: 11/20/2001)</html:td></html:tr>
<html:tr><html:td width="94" nowrap="" valign="top">12/10/2001</html:td><html:td width="60" valign="top" align="right">3</html:td><html:td valign="top"> Notice of CORPORATE disclosure by Broadcom Corporation (sm) (Entered: 12/10/2001)</html:td></html:tr>
<html:tr><html:td width="94" nowrap="" valign="top">12/14/2001</html:td><html:td width="60" valign="top" align="right"><html:a href="/cgi-bin/show_case_doc?4,52660,,,,,8">4</html:a></html:td><html:td valign="top">First Amended complaint by Broadcom Corporation , amending [1-1] complaint (exhibits not scanned) (sm) Modified on 12/18/2001 (Entered: 12/14/2001)</html:td></html:tr>
<html:tr><html:td width="94" nowrap="" valign="top">12/14/2001</html:td><html:td width="60" valign="top" align="right">&#160;</html:td><html:td valign="top">Summons(es) reissued for Intel Corporation along with amended complaint filed (sm) (Entered: 12/14/2001)</html:td></html:tr>
<html:tr><html:td width="94" nowrap="" valign="top">12/18/2001</html:td><html:td width="60" valign="top" align="right">5</html:td><html:td valign="top">Return of service executed as to Intel Corporation via personal service on 12/14/01 Answer due on 1/3/02 for Intel Corporation (sm) (Entered: 12/18/2001)</html:td></html:tr>
<html:tr><html:td width="94" nowrap="" valign="top">01/03/2002</html:td><html:td width="60" valign="top" align="right"><html:a href="/cgi-bin/show_case_doc?6,52660,,,,,11">6</html:a></html:td><html:td valign="top">Answer to first amended complaint by Intel Corporation (sm) (Entered: 01/03/2002)</html:td></html:tr>
<html:tr><html:td width="94" nowrap="" valign="top">01/03/2002</html:td><html:td width="60" valign="top" align="right">6</html:td><html:td valign="top">Counterclaim by Intel Corporation against Broadcom Corporation (sm) (Entered: 01/24/2002)</html:td></html:tr>
<html:tr><html:td width="94" nowrap="" valign="top">01/03/2002</html:td><html:td width="60" valign="top" align="right">7</html:td><html:td valign="top">MOTION by Intel Corporation to transfer case to Northern Dist of California (sm) (Entered: 01/24/2002)</html:td></html:tr>
<html:tr><html:td width="94" nowrap="" valign="top">01/07/2002</html:td><html:td width="60" valign="top" align="right"><html:a href="/cgi-bin/show_case_doc?8,52660,,,,,12">8</html:a></html:td><html:td valign="top">ORDER Setting Civil Action for Rule 16 Mgt Cnf, set management conference for 10:15 2/11/02 before Judge David Folsom ( signed by Judge David Folsom ) cc: attys of record 1/8/02 (sm) (Entered: 01/08/2002)</html:td></html:tr>
<html:tr><html:td width="94" nowrap="" valign="top">01/15/2002</html:td><html:td width="60" valign="top" align="right">9</html:td><html:td valign="top">Notice of Corporate Disclosure by Intel Corporation (sm) (Entered: 01/15/2002)</html:td></html:tr>
<html:tr><html:td width="94" nowrap="" valign="top">01/15/2002</html:td><html:td width="60" valign="top" align="right">10</html:td><html:td valign="top">Motion by Intel Corporation for John Thornburgh to appear pro hac vice (sm) (Entered: 01/15/2002)</html:td></html:tr>
<html:tr><html:td width="94" nowrap="" valign="top">01/15/2002</html:td><html:td width="60" valign="top" align="right">&#160;</html:td><html:td valign="top">PHV Filing Fee paid by atty John Thornburgh; PHV FILING FEE $ 25 RECEIPT # 96655 (sm) (Entered: 01/15/2002)</html:td></html:tr>
<html:tr><html:td width="94" nowrap="" valign="top">01/16/2002</html:td><html:td width="60" valign="top" align="right"><html:a href="/cgi-bin/show_case_doc?11,52660,,,,,16">11</html:a></html:td><html:td valign="top">ORDER granting [10-1] motion for John Thornburgh to appear pro hac vice ( signed by Judge David Folsom ) cc: attys of record 1/16/02 (sm) (Entered: 01/16/2002)</html:td></html:tr>
<html:tr><html:td width="94" nowrap="" valign="top">01/18/2002</html:td><html:td width="60" valign="top" align="right"><html:a href="/cgi-bin/show_case_doc?12,52660,,,,,18">12</html:a></html:td><html:td valign="top">Response by Broadcom Corporation to [7-1] motion to transfer case to the Northern Dist of Californiao (Exh A-N not scanned due to voluminus) (sm) (Entered: 01/22/2002)</html:td></html:tr>

</html:tbody></html:table><html:br/><html:br/><html:hr/><html:center><html:table border="1" bgcolor="WHITE" width="400"><html:tbody><html:tr><html:th colspan="4"><html:font size="+1" color="DARKRED">PACER Service Center</html:font></html:th></html:tr><html:tr><html:th colspan="4"><html:font color="DARKBLUE">Transaction Receipt</html:font></html:th></html:tr><html:tr/><html:tr/><html:tr><html:td colspan="4" align="CENTER"><html:font size="-1" color="DARKBLUE">01/16/2007 19:34:11</html:font></html:td></html:tr><html:tr><html:th align="LEFT"><html:font size="-1" color="DARKBLUE">PACER Login:</html:font></html:th><html:td align="LEFT"><html:font size="-1" color="DARKBLUE">ss5619</html:font></html:td><html:th align="LEFT"><html:font size="-1" color="DARKBLUE">Client Code:</html:font></html:th><html:td align="LEFT"><html:font size="-1" color="DARKBLUE">dev </html:font></html:td></html:tr><html:tr><html:th align="LEFT"><html:font size="-1" color="DARKBLUE">Description:</html:font></html:th><html:td align="LEFT"><html:font size="-1" color="DARKBLUE">Docket Report</html:font></html:td><html:th align="LEFT"><html:font size="-1" color="DARKBLUE">Search Criteria:</html:font></html:th><html:td align="LEFT"><html:font size="-1" color="DARKBLUE">5:01-cv-00302-DF   </html:font></html:td></html:tr><html:tr><html:th align="LEFT"><html:font size="-1" color="DARKBLUE">Billable Pages:</html:font></html:th><html:td align="LEFT"><html:font size="-1" color="DARKBLUE">27</html:font></html:td><html:th align="LEFT"><html:font size="-1" color="DARKBLUE">Cost:</html:font></html:th><html:td align="LEFT"><html:font size="-1" color="DARKBLUE"> 2.16</html:font></html:td></html:tr></html:tbody></html:table></html:center><html:hr/></html:body></html:html>
```

Stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:output method="json"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="div ul p"/>

    <xsl:key name="tables" match="table" use="@width"/>

    <xsl:variable name="atty_addr" as="map(*)">
        <xsl:map>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="key('tables', '100%')/tbody/tr[contains(td[2], 'represented')]/td[3]/text()" group-by="./preceding-sibling::b[1] => generate-id()">
                <xsl:variable name="name" select="./preceding-sibling::b[1] => normalize-space()"/>
                <xsl:variable name="address" select="current-group()[normalize-space(.)] => string-join()"/>
                <xsl:if test="not(contains($address, 'See above for address'))">
                    <xsl:map-entry key="$name" select="$address"/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:map>
    </xsl:variable>

<!--    Overrides default template for text-->
    <xsl:template match="text()"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:map>
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="flags" select="key('tables', '100%')[1]//tr/td[@align='right']"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="parties" select="key('tables', '100%')[./tbody/tr/td/b/u][1]"/>
        </xsl:map>
    </xsl:template>

<!--    Flags-->
    <xsl:template match="td" mode="flags">
        <xsl:map-entry key="'flags'" select="array{normalize-space(.) => tokenize(', ')}"/>
    </xsl:template>

<!--    Parties-->
    <xsl:template match="table" mode="parties">
        <xsl:map-entry key="'party_types'">
            <xsl:variable name="party_types" as="map(*)*">
                <xsl:for-each-group select="./tbody/tr[not(./td[1]/b/u)][./td[1]/b]" group-by="./preceding-sibling::tr[td[1]/b/u][1] => normalize-space()">
                    <xsl:map-entry key="current-grouping-key()">
                        <xsl:variable name="parties" as="map(*)*">
                           <xsl:apply-templates mode="parties" select="current-group()"/>
                        </xsl:variable>
                        <xsl:sequence select="array{$parties}"/>
                    </xsl:map-entry>
                </xsl:for-each-group>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:sequence select="array{$party_types}"/>
        </xsl:map-entry>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="tr" mode="parties">
        <xsl:map>
            <xsl:map-entry key="'name'" select="./td[1]/b => string()"/>
            <xsl:map-entry key="'represented by'">
                <xsl:variable name="represented_by" as="map(*)*">
                    <xsl:apply-templates mode="parties" select="./td[3]"/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:sequence select="array{$represented_by}"/>
            </xsl:map-entry>
        </xsl:map>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="td[b]" mode="parties">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="text() | i" group-by="./preceding-sibling::b[1] => normalize-space()">
            <xsl:map>
                <xsl:map-entry key="'name'" select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                <xsl:map-entry key="'address'" select="map:get($atty_addr, current-grouping-key())"/>
                <xsl:map-entry key="'meta'" select="array{current-group()[self::i]/string()}"/>
            </xsl:map>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Desired output:

```
{
    "party_types":
    {
        "Mediator": [
        {
            "represented by": [
            {
                "address": "Parker Clayton\n100 E Ferguson\nSuite 1114\nTyler, TX 75702\n903-533-9288\nEmail: rmparker@pbatyler.com\nPRO SE",
                "name": "Robert M Parker",
                "meta": []
            }],
            "name": "Robert M Parker"
        }],
        "Counter Claimant": [
        {
            "represented by": [
            {
                "address": "Young Pickett & Lee\n4122 Texas Blvd\nPO Box 1897\nTexarkana, TX 75504-1897\n903/794-1303\nFax: 19037925098\nEmail: dyoung@youngpickettlaw.com\n",
                "name": "Damon Michael Young",
                "meta": ["TERMINATED: 01/28/2002",
                    "LEAD ATTORNEY",
                    "ATTORNEY TO BE NOTICED"
                ]
            },
            {
                "address": "Fish & Richardson - San Diego\n12390 El Camino Real\nSan Diego, CA 92130\n858/678-5070\nFax: 858/678-5099\nEmail: thornburgh@fr.com",
                "name": "John W Thornburgh",
                "meta": []
            },
            {
                "address": "Young Pickett & Lee\n4122 Texas Blvd\nPO Box 1897\nTexarkana, TX 75504-1897\n903/794-1303\nFax: 19037945098\nEmail: wlancelee@aol.com\n",
                "name": "Lance Lee",
                "meta": ["TERMINATED: 01/28/2002"]
            },
            {
                "address": "Fish & Richardson - Dallas\n1717 Main St.\nSuite 5000\nDallas, TX 75201\n(214)747-5070\nFax: 12147472091\nEmail: mbjohnson@fr.com",
                "name": "Michael Brett Johnson",
                "meta": []
            },
            {
                "address": "Fish & Richardson - Dallas\n1717 Main St\n5000 Bank One Center\nDallas, TX 75201\n214/747-5070\nFax: 12147472091\nEmail: melsheimer@fr.com\n",
                "name": "Thomas M Melsheimer",
                "meta": ["ATTORNEY TO BE NOTICED"]
            }],
            "name": "Intel Corporation"
        }],
        "Plaintiff": [
        {
            "represented by": [
            {
                "address": "Patton & Tidwell\n4605 Texas Blvd\nPO Box 5398\nTexarkana, TX 75505-5398\n903/792-7080\nFax: 19037928233\nEmail: nickpatton@texarkanalaw.com\n",
                "name": "Nicholas H Patton",
                "meta": ["LEAD ATTORNEY", "ATTORNEY TO BE NOTICED"]
            },
            {
                "address": "Wilson Sonsini Goodrich & Rosati\n650 Page Mill Road\nPalo Alto, CA 94304-1050\n650-493-9300\nFax: 16505655100",
                "name": "Alda C Leu",
                "meta": []
            },
            {
                "address": "Kirkland & Ellis LLP - California\n555 California St\nFloor 24\nSan Francisco, CA 94104\n415/439-1452\nFax: 415/439-1352\nEmail: agarber@kirkland.com",
                "name": "Alice Catherine Garber",
                "meta": []
            },
            {
                "address": "McDermott Will & Emery\n3150 Porter Drive\nPalo Alto, Ca 94304\n650/813-500\nFax: 16508135100\n",
                "name": "Andrew S Dallmann",
                "meta": ["ATTORNEY TO BE NOTICED"]
            },
            {
                "address": "McDermott Will Emery\n3150 Porter Drive\nPalo Alto, CA 94304-1212\n650/813-5000\nFax: 16508135100\nEmail: bshariati@mwe.com",
                "name": "Behrooz Shariati",
                "meta": []
            },
            {
                "address": "Wilson Sonsini Goodrich & Rosati\n650 Page Mill Road\nPalo Alto, CA 94304-1050\n650-493-9300\nFax: 16505655100",
                "name": "Bradford J Goodson",
                "meta": []
            },
            {
                "address": "McDermott Will & Emergy\n18191 Von Karman Ave\nSuite 500\nIrvine, Ca 92612\n949-851-0633\nFax: 19498519348\nEmail: cbright@mwe.com",
                "name": "Christopher D Bright",
                "meta": []
            },
            {
                "address": "Wilson Sonsini Goodrich & Rosati\n650 Page Mill Road\nPalo Alto, CA 94304-1050\n650-493-9300\nFax: 16505655100\nEmail: dcaine@wsgr.com",
                "name": "David A Caine",
                "meta": []
            },
            {
                "address": "Wilson Sonsini Goodrich & Rosati\n650 Page Mill Road\nPalo Alto, CA 94304-1050\n650-493-9300\nFax: 650-493-9300",
                "name": "David L Fligor",
                "meta": []
            },
            {
                "address": "Wilson Sonsini Goodrich & Rosati\n650 Page Mill Road\nPalo Alto, CA 94304-1050\n650-493-9300\nFax: 650-493-9300",
                "name": "David C Wang",
                "meta": []
            },
            {
                "address": "Wilson Sonsini Goodrich & Rosati\n650 Page Mill Road\nPalo Alto, CA 94304-1050\n650-493-9300\nFax: 650-493-9300",
                "name": "Irwin R Gross",
                "meta": []
            },
            {
                "address": "Law Offices of J. Thad Heartfield\n2195 Dowlen Rd\nBeaumont, TX 77706\n409/866-3318\nFax: 14098665789\nEmail: thad@jth-law.com\n",
                "name": "J Thad Heartfield",
                "meta": ["ATTORNEY TO BE NOTICED"]
            },
            {
                "address": "Wilson Sonsini Goodrich & Rosati\n650 Page Mill Road\nPalo Alto, CA 94304-1050\n650-493-9300\nFax: 16504936811\nEmail: jyoon@wsgr.com",
                "name": "James C Yoon",
                "meta": []
            },
            {
                "address": "McDermott Will & Emergy\n18191 Von Karman Ave\nSuite 500\nIrvine, Ca 92612\n949/851-0633\nFax: 949/851-9348\nEmail: jyokoyama@mwe.com",
                "name": "Jennifer L Yokoyama",
                "meta": []
            },
            {
                "address": "Wilson Sonsini Goodrich & Rosati\n650 Page Mill Road\nPalo Alto, CA 94304-1050\n650-493-9300\nFax: 16504936811\nEmail: jholloway@wsgr.com",
                "name": "Julie M Holloway",
                "meta": []
            },
            {
                "address": "Wilson Sonsini Goodrich & Rosati\n650 Page Mill Rd\nPalo Alto, CA 94304-1050\n650/493-9300\nFax: 650/493-9300",
                "name": "Keaton S Parekh",
                "meta": []
            },
            {
                "address": "Wilson Sonsini Goodrich & Rosati\n650 Page Mill Road\nPalo Alto, CA 94304-1050\n650/565-3990\nFax: 650/493-6811\nEmail: mreed@wsgr.com",
                "name": "Matthew R Reed",
                "meta": []
            },
            {
                "address": "McDermott Will & Emergy\n18191 Von Karman Ave\nSuite 500\nIrvine, Ca 92612\n949-851-0633\nFax: 19498519348",
                "name": "Matthew F Weil",
                "meta": []
            },
            {
                "address": "Wilson Sonsini Goodrich & Rosati\n650 Page Mill Road\nPalo Alto, CA 94304-1050\n650-320-4869\nFax: 16504936811\nEmail: mladra@wsgr.com",
                "name": "Michael A Ladra",
                "meta": []
            },
            {
                "address": "McDermott Will & Emery - Irvine\n18191 Von Karman Avenue\nSuite 400\nIrvine, CA 92612-7108\n949/851-0633\nFax: 949/851-9348\nEmail: moneill@mwe.com",
                "name": "Michael R O'Neill",
                "meta": []
            },
            {
                "address": "McDermott Will & Emery\n3150 Porter Drive\nPalo Alto, Ca 94304\n650/813-500\nFax: 16508135100\n",
                "name": "Robert J Blanch",
                "meta": ["ATTORNEY TO BE NOTICED"]
            },
            {
                "address": "Wilson Sonsini Goodrich & Rosati\n650 Page Mill Road\nPalo Alto, CA 94304-1050\n650-496-4083\nEmail: rshulman@wsgr.com",
                "name": "Ron E Shulman",
                "meta": []
            },
            {
                "address": "Wilson Sonsini Goodrich & Rosati\n650 Page Mill Road\nPalo Alto, CA 94304-1050\n650-493-9300\nFax: 16505655100",
                "name": "Stephen J Ferenchick",
                "meta": []
            },
            {
                "address": "Wilson Sonsini Goodrich & Rosati\n650 Page Mill Road\nPalo Alto, CA 94304-1050\n650-493-9300\nFax: 16505655100",
                "name": "Theresa E Norton",
                "meta": []
            },
            {
                "address": "Wilson Sonsini Goodrich & Rosati\n650 Page Mill Road\nPalo Alto, CA 94304-1050\n650-493-9300\nFax: 650-493-9300",
                "name": "Tung-On Kong",
                "meta": []
            },
            {
                "address": "McDermott Will Emery\n3150 Porter Drive\nPalo Alto, CA 94304-1212\n650/813-5000\nFax: 650/813-5000",
                "name": "Vera M Elson",
                "meta": []
            }],
            "name": "Broadcom Corporation"
        }],
        "Counter Defendant": [
        {
            "represented by": [
            {
                "address": "Patton & Tidwell\n4605 Texas Blvd\nPO Box 5398\nTexarkana, TX 75505-5398\n903/792-7080\nFax: 19037928233\nEmail: nickpatton@texarkanalaw.com\n",
                "name": "Nicholas H Patton",
                "meta": ["LEAD ATTORNEY", "ATTORNEY TO BE NOTICED"]
            },
            {
                "address": "Law Offices of J. Thad Heartfield\n2195 Dowlen Rd\nBeaumont, TX 77706\n409/866-3318\nFax: 14098665789\nEmail: thad@jth-law.com\n",
                "name": "J Thad Heartfield",
                "meta": ["ATTORNEY TO BE NOTICED"]
            },
            {
                "address": "McDermott Will & Emery\n3150 Porter Drive\nPalo Alto, Ca 94304\n650/813-500\nFax: 16508135100\n",
                "name": "Andrew S Dallmann",
                "meta": ["ATTORNEY TO BE NOTICED"]
            },
            {
                "address": "McDermott Will & Emery\n3150 Porter Drive\nPalo Alto, Ca 94304\n650/813-500\nFax: 16508135100\n",
                "name": "Robert J Blanch",
                "meta": ["ATTORNEY TO BE NOTICED"]
            }],
            "name": "Broadcom Corporation"
        }],
        "Defendant": [
        {
            "represented by": [
            {
                "address": "Young Pickett & Lee\n4122 Texas Blvd\nPO Box 1897\nTexarkana, TX 75504-1897\n903/794-1303\nFax: 19037925098\nEmail: dyoung@youngpickettlaw.com\n",
                "name": "Damon Michael Young",
                "meta": ["TERMINATED: 01/28/2002",
                    "LEAD ATTORNEY",
                    "ATTORNEY TO BE NOTICED"
                ]
            },
            {
                "address": "Fish & Richardson - San Diego\n12390 El Camino Real\nSan Diego, CA 92130\n858/678-5070\nFax: 858/678-5099\nEmail: skale@fr.com",
                "name": "Andrew D Skale",
                "meta": []
            },
            {
                "address": "Fish & Richardson\n4350 La Jolla Village Drive\nSuite 500\nSan Diego, Ca 92122\n858-678-5070\nFax: 18586785099",
                "name": "Daniel T Pascucci",
                "meta": []
            },
            {
                "address": "Fish & Richardson\n12390 El Camino Real\nSan Diego, CA 92130\n858-678-5070\nFax: 18586785099\nEmail: shuman@fr.com",
                "name": "David S Shuman",
                "meta": []
            },
            {
                "address": "Provost Umphrey - Dallas\n3232 McKinney Ave\nSuite 700\nDallas, TX 75204\n214/744-3000\nFax: 12147443015\nEmail: jkendall@provostumphrey.com",
                "name": "Elton Joe Kendall",
                "meta": []
            },
            {
                "address": "McKool Smith - Dallas\n300 Crescent Court\nSuite 1500\nDallas, TX 75201\n214/978-4000\nFax: 12149784044\nEmail: gchambers@mckoolsmith.com",
                "name": "Garret Wesley Chambers",
                "meta": []
            },
            {
                "address": "Intel Corporation\n2200 Mission College Blvd SC4-202\nSanta Clara, Ca 95052\n408/765-4493\nFax: 14087655175",
                "name": "Janet Craycroft",
                "meta": []
            },
            {
                "address": "Fish & Richardson\n3300 Dain Rauscher Plaza\n60 South Sixth Street\nMinneapolis, Mn 55402\n612/335-5070\nFax: 16122889696\nEmail: dragseth@fr.com",
                "name": "John A Dragseth",
                "meta": []
            },
            {
                "address": "Fish & Richardson - San Diego\n12390 El Camino Real\nSan Diego, CA 92130\n858-678-5070\nFax: 18586785099\nEmail: gartman@fr.com",
                "name": "John E Gartman",
                "meta": []
            },
            {
                "address": "Fish & Richardson - San Diego\n12390 El Camino Real\nSan Diego, CA 92130\n858/678-5070\nFax: 858/678-5099\nEmail: thornburgh@fr.com",
                "name": "John W Thornburgh",
                "meta": []
            },
            {
                "address": "Fish & Richardson\n4350 La Jolla Village Drive\nSuite 500\nSan Diego, Ca 92122\n858-678-5070\nFax: 18586785099",
                "name": "Justin M Barnes",
                "meta": []
            },
            {
                "address": "Young Pickett & Lee\n4122 Texas Blvd\nPO Box 1897\nTexarkana, TX 75504-1897\n903/794-1303\nFax: 19037945098\nEmail: wlancelee@aol.com\n",
                "name": "Lance Lee",
                "meta": ["TERMINATED: 01/28/2002"]
            },
            {
                "address": "Keker & Van Nest\n710 Sansome St\nSan Francisco, CA 94111\n415/391-5400\nFax: 14153977188",
                "name": "Lloyd A Farnham",
                "meta": []
            },
            {
                "address": "Fish & Richardson - Dallas\n1717 Main St.\nSuite 5000\nDallas, TX 75201\n(214)747-5070\nFax: 12147472091\nEmail: mbjohnson@fr.com",
                "name": "Michael Brett Johnson",
                "meta": []
            },
            {
                "address": "Keker & Van Nest\n710 Sansome St\nSan Francisco, CA 94111\n415/391-5400\nFax: 14153977188\nEmail: rvn@kvn.com",
                "name": "Robert A Van Nest",
                "meta": []
            },
            {
                "address": "Attorney at Law\nP O Box O\nMarshall, TX 75671\n903/927-2111\nFax: 19039272622\nEmail: sbaxter@mckoolsmith.com\n",
                "name": "Samuel Franklin Baxter",
                "meta": ["ATTORNEY TO BE NOTICED"]
            },
            {
                "address": "Fish & Richardson - San Diego\n12390 El Camino Real\nSan Diego, CA 92130\n858-678-4343\nEmail: sproul@fr.com",
                "name": "Seth M Sproul",
                "meta": []
            },
            {
                "address": "Keker & Van Nest\n710 Sansome St\nSan Francisco, CA 94111\n415/391-5400\nFax: 14153977188",
                "name": "Stuart L Gasner",
                "meta": []
            },
            {
                "address": "Fish & Richardson - Dallas\n1717 Main St\n5000 Bank One Center\nDallas, TX 75201\n214/747-5070\nFax: 12147472091\nEmail: melsheimer@fr.com\n",
                "name": "Thomas M Melsheimer",
                "meta": ["ATTORNEY TO BE NOTICED"]
            }],
            "name": "Intel Corporation"
        }],
        "Amicus": [
        {
            "represented by": [
            {
                "address": "Cox and Smith\n112 E. Pecan Street\nSuite 1800\nSan Antonio, TX 78205-1521\nPRO SE",
                "name": "Gail Peterson",
                "meta": []
            }],
            "name": "Gail Peterson"
        }]
    },
    "flags": ["CLOSED", "FRC", "JURY", "MEDIATION"]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're trying to do too much in one transformation. Start by splitting the problem into two phases: an up-conversion phase where you get the input document into sensible shape, followed by an extraction phase where you extract the information you're looking for. This approach will simplify the problem, and the first phase is reusable for when you want to extract something different.

The intermediate "up-converted" form could be JSON or XML, or you could do XML to JSON conversion as another processing phase between the other two. The more you can split your complex task into a sequence of simpler tasks, the easier it will be.

I can't see where the problem with "mode" arose, but then I'm not sure whether the XSLT code shown is before or after the change you describe. SaxonJS, however, is less "smart" about apply-templates than SaxonJ, it's more inclined to do a complete search of all the template rules in the chosen mode. This might be the issue, but I don't see a large number of template rules, so I may have got the wrong end of the stick.

It's unclear to me, reading your post again, whether this is a problem in achieving the functionality required, or in writing good XSLT code to achieve it, or in achieving improved performance. In short, it's not really clear what your problem is: perhaps you need to address one concern at a time.

Comment: Thank you, have been simplifying the initial extraction and doing more processing on a second pass. I was unclear on the "mode" issue. Using "mode" fixed a performance problem, but I was unsure if the way I was using it presently was poor style.